# C code to UML generator for linux

Tags: uml

Please tell me if there is a C code to UML diagram generator. I need to operate it in linux. All the UML generators that i found were for C++ or Java and none of them for C.

Comment: Assuming class diagram as expected output?

Comment: Guess why. C in contrast to the others is not OO. Sure you can program OO with C (or COBOL or whatever). But for good reasons there are languages like C++ etc. that directly support OO (/UML). C is fine for machine code. But when you're in OO you shall use an OO language.